# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) spring boot api

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running spring boot with aws elastic beanstalk but when I deploy it , it errored as 502 bad gateway.

I have tried all the solutions related to this error

1. I have changed the SERVER_PORT to 5000
2. I have changed the security inbound rules in RDS and EC2 TCP 5000 anywhere

here are the last 100 logs errors:

```
2021/11/18 02:00:29 [error] 15036#15036: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 94.129.70.0, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "rentedbooksapi-env-1.eba-pddpv5ew.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"


2021/11/18 02:00:29 [error] 15036#15036: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 94.129.70.0, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", "
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?